# ReCaptchaNoCaptcha support for VisualEditor in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, captcha, installation

Need help with MediaWiki installation. I successfully installed MediaWiki. Added VisualEditor and Mobilefrontend.

With this in place you can edit my site using visual editor but you cannot save it because of ConfirmEdit ReCaptchaNoCaptcha.  Also in mobile, VisualEditor is not loading at all. ConfirmEdit Simple CAPTCHA is working fine only ReCaptchaNoCaptcha is not working with VisualEditor.

If you look at https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-VisualEditor/blob/master/modules/ve-mw/init/ve.init.mw.ArticleTarget.js

You can see

> "API for different things in the UI. At this point we only support the
>   SimpleCaptcha and FancyCaptcha"

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If the developers say it isn't supported, it sounds like it wouldn't be an easy fix.  Have you tried asking them what it would take?

Comment: This is not a priority for them. I can see posts from 2015 itself asking this. If we can find which file or block of code talking with ConfirmEdit. I think we can fix by writing some JS or PHP.

Comment: If you are looking for code, then this isn't the right place to ask.